# In what cases will a 'release' call recur?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, nsautoreleasepool

I have a segmentation fault (`SIGSEGV`) with the following stack-trace:

```
Thread 6 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     objc_msgSend (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 16
1   CoreData                            -[NSManagedObject release] (in CoreData) + 160
2   libobjc.A.dylib                     object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 148
3   libobjc.A.dylib                     objc_destructInstance (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 92
4   CoreData                            _PFDeallocateObject (in CoreData) + 28
5   MyApp                               -[Job dealloc] (in MyApp) (Job.m:113)
6   CoreData                            -[_PFManagedObjectReferenceQueue _queueForDealloc:] (in CoreData) + 272
7   CoreData                            -[NSManagedObject release] (in CoreData) + 160
8   CoreData                            -[_PFArray dealloc] (in CoreData) + 100
9   libobjc.A.dylib                     (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 564
```

Note that the `dealloc` method in the `Job` class is empty/a no-op.  It appears to be a vestigial remnant from before the code was converted to ARC.

What strikes me as strange in the stack-trace is that there's a call to `[NSMangedObject release]` which leads to a subsequent call to `[NSManagedObject release]` before it completes.  That gives the appearance of recursion, though my guess is that probably the second call is to some other `NSManagedObject` instance and no actual recursion is occurring.

But what are the cases in which this will occur?  From the name of the preceding method in the chain (`object_cxxDestructFromClass`), it seems that the runtime is deallocating any class member-variables that may exist.  Is that correct?

The `Job` class does have an `ivar` field which is used to keep a transient reference to another `NSManagedObject` instance, so is this crash occurring when the runtime attempts to release the instance referenced by the `ivar` (which, it would appear, has already been released)?

Comment: 1. Yes, this is no recursion. 2. Post the complete log message. 3. Did you sad something about reference counting and automatic reference counting?

Comment: 1) Thanks,  2) What benefit do you expect to gain from the rest of the crash report?  If there was anything useful, I'd have included it.  The only other reference to `MyApp` is in `main()`, and all the other threads are just off doing normal things in `libsystem`, `CFNetwork`, `CoreMotion`, and other things that my app isn't using directly, 3) Yes, the app is currently using ARC, but wasn't originally.  It has some remnants of its original state, such as `dealloc` implementations that are literally just `- (void) dealloc {}`.

Comment: Managed object A was released while have a relationship to managed object B, triggering the release of managed object B.   Nothing unusual about that and, yes, the destruct is likely just normal ivar cleanup (leading to the release and dealloc).   This looks like a fairly typical over-release and the allocations instrument should help debug it.

Comment: 2) Obviously somebody thought that this information could be helpful. Additionally you are obviously new to reference counting on Objective-C. So maybe you should not decide to remove information you consider to be useless. And I did not say that you should include the other thread's stack.

Comment: @bbum Using ARC makes it unlikely to have an overrelease, even it is possible. However, using instrument can help.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad could be third party code in play or incomplete conversion; most converted code bases end up with a handful of non-arc'd files.  Doesn't matter if it is arc or not, that still looks like an over release given the information provided.   Could also be a memory stomper; overwriting the isa will do the same.

Comment: @bbum Of course. But exactly this would be interesting. I do not have the impression that the Op read an introduction to reference counting.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad - You're basing that impression on what, exactly?

Comment: Based on the Q in the middle of your posting. The fact that releases are chained by the "member variables" (they are called ivars for instance variables) is one basic idea of RC.